# Suppose that $F^\prime (x) = 1/(x^ p + 4)$ , where $p > 1$. Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I am not sure exactly where to start - it seems to me that I'll be using definition of a $p$-series.

Any tips on a starting point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F^\prime (x) = 1/(x^p + 4) > 0$, the function $F(x)$ is increasing. Then 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} F(x)$$ exists by a well-known result. See f.i. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757079/prove-that-the-limit-exists-of-an-increasing-and-bounded-function).

EDIT:
(After a hint from Daniel Fischer) If you also need to prove that $F(x)$ converges to a finite value, note that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} F^\prime (s) ds =  \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \int_0^x \frac {1}{1+s^p} ds < \infty$$
because $p>1$.

Answer (score 3):

$p>1\implies \int_0^{+\infty}\frac {dt}{4+t^p}$ convergent

$$\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x F'(t)dt \in\mathbb R$$

$$\implies\lim_{x\to+\infty}(F (x) -F (0))\in \mathbb R $$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to+\infty}F (x)\in\mathbb R $$

Answer (score 0):

By the FTC, we have

\begin{align*}
F(x) &= F(1) + \int_{t=1}^x F'(t)\,dt\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\\[4pt]
&= F(1) + \int_{t=1}^x\frac{1}{t^p+4}\,dt\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
$\\[-2pt]$
\begin{align*}
\text{Hence}\;\;&\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x)\;\;\;\text{exists}\\[4pt]
\iff\; &\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{t=1}^x\frac{1}{t^p+4}\,dt\;\;\;\text{exists}\\[4pt]
\iff\; &\int_{t=1}^\infty\frac{1}{t^p+4}\,dt\;\;\;\text{exists}\\[4pt]
\iff\; &\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p+4}\;\;\;\text{converges [applying the integral test]}\\[4pt]
\iff\; &\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p}\;\;\;\text{converges [applying the limit comparison test]}\\[-8pt]
&\qquad\qquad\text{which converges by the p-series test}
\end{align*}