# If $f \colon [a,\infty) \longrightarrow\mathbb R$, $f$ monotonically increasing and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists then it is also upper bounded

Tags: calculus, limits, monotone-functions

Prove that if $f\colon[a,\infty)\longrightarrow R$, $f$ monotonically increasing and
$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists then it is also upper bounded

How do I prove this?

The only thing that I could find was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757079/prove-that-the-limit-exists-of-an-increasing-and-bounded-function) but it requires to prove that limit exists given that f is already bounded above and increasing.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of what this kind of $f$ would look like? After drawing those pictures, do you see a candidate for what an upper bound on $f$ could be?

Comment: Well, it would certainly increase. But how can I assume the upper bound? There is no info about the value of the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$. Could there be a $x_0\in[a,+\infty)$ such that $f(x_0)>M$? No, because $f$ is monotonically increasing and\begin{align}f(x_0)>M&\implies\bigl(\forall x\in[x_0,+\infty)\bigr):f(x)\geqslant f(x_0)>M\\&\implies\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)\geqslant f(x_0)>M,\end{align}which is a contradiction, since $M=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The clue was after all to assume that value of M is finite number

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try a proof by contradiction. If $f$ were not bounded from above and monotonically increasing, can you show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist?

Comment: wouldn't in that case the limit be equal to $\infty$ ?

Comment: @jimogios Typically, "the limit exists" means "the limit is a finite number." So "the limit is $\infty$" would fall under the category of "the limit does not exist."

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks.